# O365 Cloud Accounts Fail To Log On When Accessing SharePoint Online URL Directly

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, authentication, adfs, federation

When we try to use a @ourdomain.onmicrosoft.com account to log in directly to a SharePoint Online site we get redirected to our ADFS STS login page.  This fails to log in with the correct credentials.

If we log in at, for example, portal.office.com first and then navigate to the same SharePoint Online site we can access fine.

How do we log in with these cloud accounts without first having to log in via the Microsoft login page?